# Where can you get a photon detector?

Tags: experimental-physics, photons, double-slit-experiment, particle-detectors

Say I'm doing the double-slit experiment with photons as the particle and want to add a detector just behind each slit to eliminate the interference pattern.  Where would I get a detector like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're based on photomultiplier tubes.  An example is referred to in this [lab assignment](http://panda3.phys.unm.edu/nmcpp/gold/phys493L/lab6.pdf).

> Photon Detector: The detectors used in this experiment are two
>   Hamamatsu R1527 photomultiplier tubes (PMTs)